# Symfony 1.4 cookie retrieval failure

Tags: php, cookies, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am trying to store variables in cookies, using the Symfony 1.4 framework. Here is a snippet of my sfAction derived class:

```
class productActions extends sfActions
{
    public function preExecute()
    {
        $this->no_registration_form = true;
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $cookie_value = $request->getCookie('pcatid');
        $this->prod_category_id = (!isset($cookie_value)) ? 0 : $cookie_value;

        $cookie_value = $request->getCookie('pitid');
        $this->product_item_id = (!isset($cookie_value)) ? 0 : $cookie_value;

        $cookie_value = $request->getCookie('pcatnm');
        $this->product_category_name = (!isset($cookie_value)) ? null : base64_decode ($cookie_value);

        $cookie_value = $request->getCookie('pipnm');
        $this->product_info_partial_name = (!isset($cookie_value)) ? null : $cookie_value;

        $cookie_value = $request->getCookie('protl');
        $this->title = (!isset($cookie_value)) ? null : base64_decode ($cookie_value);
    }

    public function postExecute()
    {
        $expire = time()+2592000;
        $path = '/products/';
        $response = $this->getResponse();

        $value = $this->prod_category_id;
        if (isset($value))
            $response->setCookie('pcatid', $value, $expire, $path);

        $value = $this->product_item_id;
        if (isset($value))
            $response->setCookie('pitid', $value, $expire, $path);

        $value = base64_encode($this->product_category_name);
        if (isset($value))
            $response->setCookie('pcatnm', $value, $expire, $path);

        $value = $this->product_info_partial_name;
        if (isset($value))
            $response->setCookie('pipnm', $value, $expire, $path);

        $value = base64_encode($this->title);
        if (isset($value))
            $response->setCookie('protl', $value, $expire, $path);        
    }

    public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        // uses defaults or settings stored in cookies
    }

    ... // other functions that set the required instance member fields
}
```

I have stepped through the code in a debug session, and I can see that the cookie values are being collated in the `sfWebResponse` variable - however, no cookies are being set - and this is demonstrated in the `preExecute()` function - all the cookies retrieved have value null.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are the cookies set when you check in browser?

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski: Yes the cookies are set when I check the brower (FF). The problem appears therefore, to lie with the retrieval code. I will ammend the title to reflect this.

Comment: Does `var_dump($_COOKIE)` inside the `preExecute` show your cookies?

Comment: @j0k: `var_dump($_COOKIE)` inside `preExecute()` shows the **existing** cookies, but crucially, not the ones I am setting in my `postExecute`.

Comment: Can we see an action exemple? Cookies are setted when the `sfWebResponse` send header. So I'm wondering if the tested action send the header properly (I mean, using a normal layout, etc ..)

Comment: @j0k: There is nothing special about the actions, apart from containing logic to set the various instance members. My index action for example, has no logic whatsoever, and simply uses default values or whatever values were stored in cookies (at least, that is the desired behaviour). I have added my `index` action as an example, as requested.

Comment: The action doesn't end up with `return sfView::ERROR` or `return sfView::SUCCESS`, or a redirect, or `die()`. It ends up *normally* ?

Comment: @j0k: I'm not sure I understand your question. All actions return with `sfView::SUCCESS` unless **specifically** stated otherwise (e.g. `return 'foo'` or `return sfView::ERROR`). In other words `sfView::SUCCESS` is returned by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a simple test on a fresh symfony project.

I've copy/pasted your `preExecute` & `postExecute` and I've added a simple action with an empty template:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  var_dump($_COOKIE);

  $this->prod_category_id          = 123;
  $this->product_item_id           = 456;
  $this->product_category_name     = 789;
  $this->product_info_partial_name = 159;
  $this->title                     = 753;
}
```

And I've changed this line `$path = '/products/';` to `$path = '/';`.

On the first try, I don't have any cookies so I've nothing:

```
array
  empty
```

And on refresh, cookies were defined and I can see them:

```
array
  'symfony' => string 'c04khrspp5fmg3sh797uq9c9s1' (length=26)
  'pcatid' => string '123' (length=3)
  'pitid' => string '456' (length=3)
  'pcatnm' => string 'Nzg5' (length=4)
  'pipnm' => string '159' (length=3)
  'protl' => string 'NzUz' (length=4)
```

**What can be wrong** from your code, is that you set the cookie path to `/products/`. Which means, you'll be able to access these cookie **only** when your are on `http://exemple.com/products/...`.

If you try to access these cookies on `http://exemple.com/`, you'll get nothing.

If this doesn't solve your problem, could you paste an example of an actions from where you got the problem with the defined uri (at least the part after the domain).

Comment: Changing the path from `/products` (which is what I wanted) to `/` allows the cookies to be correctly set. Is there any reason why I can't store/retrieve them under `/products/` ?. the url shown in the browser is `http://example.com/products/foo/foobar.html`

Comment: Actually, I think I know why. I am in the dev env, so my url's look like: http://localhost/frontend_dev.php/products/foo/foobar.html. I'll just accept your answer. At least it works now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's what I've just tested. Since you defined `/products` your url must be `exemple.com/products`, as you said, it won't work if you are on the dev controller.

Comment: Ooops! - I forgot to award bounty (assumed it automatically got awarded when I accepted your answer) - anyway, done now - enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the $path to the method you can only use the cookie when accessing the cookie from the same URL.

If you want to access a cookie from all the site, don't pass anything in the path.

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setCookie('stack', 'This cookie is readable from all site for the next 60 segs.', time() + 60);
$response->setCookie('overflow', 'This cookie is readable from mypage for the next 60 segs.', time() + 60, 'http://mysite.com/mypage');
```